# Why does no window open when I try to run a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm using a new computer that runs on Windows 10 pro, and I can't run a shiny app on it. I first tried with a shiny app that I wrote myself. In R Studio, when I click on "Run App", nothing happens, there is no error message but the window freezes. The same thing happens if I try to runExample("01_hello"). No message error appears, no window opens, and the RStudio window freezes.

I have tried to select "Run in Window", "Run in Viewer Pane" and "Run external" in the "Run App" menu, but this doesn't change a thing.

Would anyone have an idea of what could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What versions of R, shiny, and Rstudio do you have installed? Have you tried updating all of them?

Comment: Hi @Phil,
I have the most recent version for all 3: R 4.1.0 and shiny 1.6.0

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with R 4.1.0, shiny 1.6.0 and RStudio 1.4.1722 on a Windows machine.

Comment: I tried on another computer that runs with windows 10 pro, R 4.1.0, shiny 1.6.0 and RStudio 1.4.1106 and everything works fine. The computer on which I can't run shiny apps has RStudio 1.4.1717 installed. Would someone know what could be going wrong with this computer? Or what I could check to get the beginning of an answer? I have no clue of what might be going wrong unfortunately.

Comment: I noticed that, on other computers, this message appears when I run the app "Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7062", but this message doesn't appear on the computer where I cannot launch apps from.

I tried typing
runApp("path_to_the_app", display.mode = "showcase", host = "127.0.0.1")
but again, nothing happens: no error message, no window opens.

Comment: What if you try with the preview version installed https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/ ? Also, what is your OS and processor?